Google Trimmed Match install issue
I'm trying to install trimmed_match from GitHub on my own machine so I can use excel rather than Google Sheets but whenever I try to pip install trimmed match I get the following error when it begins building the wheel:
Building wheels for collected packages: trimmed_match
  Building wheel for trimmed_match (pyproject.toml): started
  Building wheel for trimmed_match (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
Failed to build trimmed_match
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Building wheel for trimmed_match (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [5 lines of output]
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\trimmed_match
  error: could not create 'build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\trimmed_match': Cannot create a file when that file already exists
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for trimmed_match
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (trimmed_match)

I used choco to install Bazel and Bazelisk, I have setuptools and git installed and I cloned the repo to my local drive but I still can't seem to get it running on my local machine.
The file it's saying already exists but I can't locate it.
Has anyone else come across this issue or a similar one?
I used choco to install Bazel and Bazelisk, I have setuptools and git installed and I cloned the repo to my local drive but I still can't seem to get it running on my local machine.
The file it's saying already exists but I can't locate it.
